# check the value of dictionary in array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

My json file:

```
[{
    "cardId": "1412015 T",
    "firstname": "Abesh",
    "lastname": "Shakya",
    "designation": "Jr. System Administrator",
    "department": "Technology"    
 },
 {
    "cardId": "1412015 T",
    "firstname": "Rbesh",
    "lastname": "Shakya",
    "designation": "Jr. System Administrator",
    "department": "Admin"
}
]
```

how to apply for loop and add if condition so that if department is techology the save  firstname and lastname value in techname array otherwise adminName array

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you unpacked the JSON?

Comment: yes, from array i want to list in table view

Comment: Show how you parse JSON what apprcouh you are using. Do not ask to do it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you downloaded some data from the server. You will convert the data into a dictionary using

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
    data,
    options: .AllowFragments
)

var techNames  : [String] = []
var adminNames : [String] = []
```

Then you can iterate doing

```
for dictionary in arrayOfDictionaries {

    if dictionary["department"] == "Technology" {

        // Add name to techNames
        techNames.append(completeNameForPerson(dictionary))

    } else {

        // Do something else
        adminNames.append(completeNameForPerson(dictionary))
    }
}

func completeNameForPerson(person : [String : String]) -> String {

    return "\(person["firstname"]!) \(person["lastname"]!)"
}
```

This is a common question, please, search before opening a new discussion thread.

Comment: how to add firstname  value in new array

Comment: I updated the code